# Difference between creating a secondary index vs creating an index CF manually in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

Can anyone tell me the differnce between creating a secondary index vs creating an index CF manually in Cassandra

Answer (score 0):

Secondary indexes in Cassandra are stored and maintained on each node. Thus, when you filter by a secondary index, Cassandra will need to do the search on every node, and then return the combined results. Therefore, filtering by secondary indexes can be significantly slower than filtering by partition key (according to my tests it can be 10 times slower, depending on your data and topology).

Maintaining your own index table is more efficient for most use cases, but you need to deal with updating the index table on your own. Also, you will need to do two queries for retrieving your data: one that queries the index table, and another one for retrieving the actual data.

Another solution would be to duplicate your data completely, and create two tables with the same structure, but different keys.

If performance is your key concern, then go for an index table or a duplicated table. If you need simplicity and can afford some performance penalty, use secondary indexes, but I recommend to do some performance testing beforehand.